# strategy of publication fee for a junior faculty member in math/phys fields

Tags: publications, mathematics, physics, open-access

Most good journals don't charge a mandatory publication fee. Many open access only journals aren't that good and accept papers easily. For a junior faculty member who has much money for publication in the budget, it's a good chance to boost the number of publications by resorting to open access journals. Is it a good strategy, how should they organize/allocate the money? What should they think about before publishing on open access only journals that aren't among the top ones?

Comment: For math, I don't know of more than 1 reputable journal that charges a fee.  Journals that charge a fee aren't 'not among the top ones' - they are (with that exception) among the bottom ones, or predatory.  To me, a large number of not-so-good papers makes you look worse, not better; when I evaluate candidates, papers in bottom-tier journals beyond the first one or two have negative value.

Comment: You ask for a strategy.  A strategy to achieve what goal?

Comment: If the goal is to get promoted, ask your department chair.  Don't listen to the opinions of people not familiar with your university.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist makes sense

Comment: @AlexanderWoo makes sense

Answer (score 6):

**If your T&P Committee is worth their salt, they'll see through tons of crappy publications**. As a new faculty member, it is difficult to live with the pressure of needing to publish as you are setting up your career. However, publications are *evaluated* by your peers, with the hope that they advance the field. Simply publishing to get numbers up is a bad idea. Instead, you should focus on publishing quality research. Ostensibly, as a PhD student you learned how to perform this research and became an expert in your field. As such, it is now your job to prove it, and set up and continue a career of research excellence.

If you publish great results in low-tier journals, you've wasted those good results on something that people will never read. If you publish bad results in low-tier journals, your T&P committee will see through it and realize that you're trying to pad your paper count. Either way, it doesn't seem like low-tier journals are the answer...

Note: low-tier and low-circulation are NOT the same thing. If your field is highly specialized the "the important journal" may be very small indeed. Low-tier is...well, what you said - easy to get into because the standards are not high.

Comment: "you've wasted those good results on something that people will never read"  People keep claiming that prestigious journals are read more frequently, but I still do not believe it.  People decide what to read based on search results.

Comment: Academic journals have not had meaningful "circulation" in decades.  Libraries buy subscription journals in bulk.

Comment: thanks, though there are always people publishing on not-so-good journals, for there's little space for all to publish on good journals.

Comment: @feynman I think "not so good" and "predatory" are very different things. My interpretation of your question was that you would be submitting research to what is essentially a for-sure acceptance, pay-to-play journal. Every field certainly has its top-tier, mid-tier, low-tier, and crap journals, and low-tier stuff isn't always bad

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky right that's the point of my question. How should we understand low-tier stuff isn't always bad?

Comment: @feynman Oh, I see. As it is written you aren't asking about low-tier but predatory journals. At least that's how most of us interpreted that. I think the answer is that the experts of the field know which journals are high and low tier, so your T&P committee would evaluate that. If you publish a ton of bad results in low-tier journals that's a problem, but lots of small, useful, incremental results in low-tier journals and some great results in high tier would look different

Answer (score 3):

Publishing in low quality journal is never a good strategy.  Other researchers will read your grant applications and your PTR file and the first thing they will look for is journal name recognition, in particular if you publish in the journal they publish in.  Even a few "good papers" drowned in a see of bad papers will not impress anyone.

Open access doesn't imply predatory and many universities or conglomerate of universities now have deals to reduced or 0 APC in gold open access journals.  Universities are unlikely to strike such a deal with predatory publishers so one way to "vet" open-access journal is to see if indeed your institution has some deal with the publisher.  It's not a hard-and-fast rule of course but the number of deals so negotiated between publishers and institutions is increasing.

Although superficially discouraging, there's actually a benefit in submitting to a top (or at least reasonably good) journal: the process will function as an initial quality assessment of your work.  If your submission is systematically desk rejected in topical journals, you're in trouble and it's likely any referee for a grant or on some tenure committee would likely reach the same conclusion as to the quality of that particular piece of work.  Even if the paper is rejected at the referee level, you are likely to get (not in all cases but at least a majority of the time) constructive comments on the contents, and you can take it from there.  The disadvantage of this is that you need to do extra work to get it published but most communities are now increasingly aware of papermills so publishing multiple papers with only tiny variations in contents is not necessarily optimal either.

Certainly where I work papers in predatory journals are automatically struck off the CV and reflect very poorly on any candidate.  Candidates for promotion or tenure are pretty systematically asked to explain their choice of journals, and candidates can have a very difficult time defending such publishing practices.